# Json out from sql query unable to deliver the expected output

Tags: sql-server, json, highcharts

data.php file:

```
$sql = "SELECT [name],[Prev Year],[PY_mkr_col],[PY_sg_col] FROM 
dbo.s5_test";

$result = sqlsrv_query($con, $sql);;

$category = array(); $category['name'] = 'month'; 
$series1 = array(); 
$series1['name'] = 'Prev Year';
$series1['color'] = 'PY_mkr_col';
$series1['segmentColor'] = 'PY_sg_col';

while($r = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
    $category['data'][] = $r['name']; 
    $series1['data'][] = $r['Prev Year']; 
} 

$result = array(); 
array_push($result,$category); 
array_push($result,$series1);
print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); 
sqlsrv_close($con);
?>
```

Output Json:

```
[{"name":"month","data":
["Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec","Jan","Feb","Mar"]},
{"name":"Prev Year","color":"PY_mkr_col","segmentColor":"PY_sg_col","data":
[140,154,138,173,144,148,168,130,143,137,171,125]}]
```

Expected Output:

PY_mkr_col and PY_sg_col should contain the below values

PY_mkr_col:

```
   ['rba(128,128,128,0)', green, 
    'blue','rba(128,128,128,0)', green, 'blue','rba(128,128,128,0)', green, 
    'blue','rba(128,128,128,0)', green, 'blue']
```

PY_sg_col:

```
 [#FF0000, #008000,#FF0000, #008000,#FF0000,  
      #008000,#FF0000, #008000,#FF0000, #008000,#FF0000, #008000]<br>
```

In the SQL Table the values 'rba(128,128,128,0)', 'green' and #FF0000 are formatted as nvarchar(40).

This Json output will be passed as the Series[] in the highcharts with `Multi_color.js` library.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Could you create a working example in jsfiddle?

Comment: @stpoa : please find the fiddle "http://jsfiddle.net/mailsakthi/1rv5jr65/3/"

Comment: Your chart seems to render ok, could you be more specific about desired output?

Comment: In my previous fiddle i tried to keep the data static and generated the chart. Now I am trying it to generate the same chart by using data from mssql and converting it to JSON and then use the data, color, and segment Color all from the mssql table and I am failing , please see this fiddle with my code: https://jsfiddle.net/mailsakthi/Lbuwbyns/2/ let me know if I can be of any further information.

Comment: Maybe just pass whole series config as JSON using jquery's getJSON method. http://jsfiddle.net/2hv2o61x/